# Google Tag Manager - Trigger For When Text Appears

Tags: google-tag-manager

There is a button on one of my pages that I need to track on Google tag manager. I need to create a tag for when a user clicks the button and receives the message "Success! It looks like your DNS is properly configured!"

I am awful at coding, and have tried many different variations of triggers to try to accomplish this. Could someone think of a way for me to do this? (If you could create a step by step process, that would be amazing.)

Again, I need to track ONLY when they click and receive the message "Success!..."

Thanks!

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
  <div id="dns-loading" class="alert alert-info dns-alert" role="alert">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
    Checking your DNS configuration...
  </div>
  <div id="dns-good" class="alert alert-success dns-alert" role="alert">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>
    Success! It looks like your DNS is properly configured!
  </div>
  <div id="dns-bad" class="alert alert-danger dns-alert" role="alert">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
    Something went wrong! It appears your DNS is misconfigured. If you
    recently set your IP address range, please allow a few minutes for this
    data to propagate to our DNS servers.
  </div>
  <center>
    <div id="dns-button" class="btn btn-block btn-info">
      Test DNS
    </div>
    <img id="dns-img" width="0" height="0"/>
  </center>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Just brainstorming, one possibility is to write a timer on the page that polls for the text assuming the text only appears if it's of a certain class (ie. "show").

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:
Check "Check Validation" in your Trigger Configuration.
Then, right below *"Enable this trigger when all of these conditions are true"* you can use a variable like DOM Element to verify if a text exists in DOM.

I think this might work.
Here is an example:

[image: Check Validation and DOM Element]